# Define a function using a variable?

Tags: python, string, integer, digits

I am trying to define a function that will include a variable `n` where `n` will be a string of numbers e.g. `"3884892993"`, the definition of the function starts as `is_true(n)`, however if n is going to be a string should it be `is_true(n)` and then once the string is defined I can test the function with an example string such as `n = "3884892993"`. I get a syntax error when I use `is_true(n)` however. And I am just wondering how I would go about testing this function with an example string for n.

My entire function to define is shown here: http://oi44.tinypic.com/282i3qo.jpg but bear in mind I am an absolute novice so there will most probably be many mistakes, but I would appreciate some help from some experts if at all possible :)

```
def is_valid("n"): #n is the number to be checked.
    number = 
    [int(y) for y in A] #converts the string into a list of useable digits.
    altern1 = integer[-2::-2] #sets altern1 as one set of alternating digits.
    double = [x*2 for x in altern1] #doubles each element of the list altern1.
    sum1 = sum(double) # adds together all the doubled items of the list.
    altern2 = integer[-1::-2] #sets altern2 as the other set of alternating digits.
    return sum2 = sum(altern2)#sums the other set of alternating digits.
    sumtotal = sum1 + sum2 #works out the total sum to be worked with.
    for mod = sumtotal % 10: #works out remainder when sumtotal is divided by 10
        if mod == 0 : #if remainder is zero sumtotal is a multiple of 10
            print 'True' #sumtotal is a multiple of 10 therefore n is a credit card number
        else:
            print 'False' #sumtotal is NOT a multiple of 10 therefore not a valid credit card number
```

**Here is the actual question:**

The algorithm for verifying a number is as follows:
(a) Starting with the penultimate digit, and working towards the rst digit, double each alternating digit.
(b) Sum the doubled digits, treating 13 as 1+3, etc, and add the result to the sum of the undoubled
digits
(c) If the sum is divisible by 10 the number is a valid credit card number.

Write and test a function is_valid() which takes as an argument a credit card number as a string
(eg is valid("49927398716")) and returns True or False depending on whether the number is a
valid credit card number.

Comment: Well I just thought it would be easier using snipping tool than pasting it into here and making sure it hand the right indentation (which is probably wrong anyway). That is how muhc of a novice I am. Also it was meant to be PNG, sorry about that.

Comment: Could you please print out the JPEG of your code, place it on a [wooden table](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Web_0_0x2e_1.aspx), and take a photo of it?

Comment: @ Adam Rosenfield I'll assume that was sarcasm haha, I've put up the raw code.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for a good laugh. George: yes, that was sarcasm ;) But it was very friendly.  "We" (meaning SO-ers) need the raw code so we can copy/paste/run your code.  Your question will get a lot more (helpful) answers if you post something we can run that way.  Welcome to S.O.

Comment: @George: Yes, it was a joke; I figured it might have gone over people's heads without the link.

Comment: Well at least now you know how little I know of programming, I have been failing at it for 3 weeks so far haha.

Comment: Have you worked through a good tutorial? Normally I don't recommend Dive Into Python ( http://diveintopython.nfshost.com/toc/index.html ) to programming novices, but from your earlier question it seems like you're aware of a lot of the important stuff and just haven't figured out how to put it together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is your question, but if you are trying to:

- correctly define the function:

  - pay attention to the indentation (this is required by Python!),
  - see [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/function.html) for examples of function definitions,
- convert a string variable into integer, you can do this:

  ```
  new_var = int(old_var)
  ```

  Generally please pay attention to types, because it is not like in some other dynamically typed languages and strings are not dynamically converted into numbers - you should do it explicitly.
- read the value of the variable, based on its name:

  ```
  my_var = vars().get('variable_name')
  ```

  (where `variable_name` is the name of the variable and optionally you can give context within brackets after `vars` - see `help(vars)` for details)

Did any of the above solve your problem?

**EDIT (based on the clarification):**

This should solve your problem:

```
def is_true(my_variable):
    # Here the variable named "my_variable" is accessible
```

If you want to do something "in-place" on the passed variable, I have a bad news: **strings and integers are immutable in Python**, thus you are not able to simply change them - you should probably return them as a result of the function (there are at least two workarounds, but I do not recommend them if you are a novice in Python).

**EDIT (for proper code styling):**

You should probably read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to get familiar with what is the coding standard for Python scripts - this is commonly used across Python community and you should follow that (at some point you should appreciate it).

Comment: Hi, basically I just wanted a way for the function to read whatever string replaces "n" and then carry out the operations on it.

Comment: @GeorgeBurrows: Ok, I have just updated my answer so it probably answers your questions better.

Comment: Hi, so essentially I can't test the code with a string? If so that's midly irritating as spotting the problems will be fairly impossible for me now haha, thanks for the help.

Comment: @GeorgeBurrows: Of course you can. What I am saying is that you should not expect the variable you pass to the function to be changed after the function is invoked. You should not also think `'3' / 1` is the same as `3 / 1` (and you usually can not perform on string an action you would be able to perform on integer). Is it clear enough?

Answer (score 4):

Quotes are only used for string literals, you wouldn't enclose a variable or parameter name in quotes to indicate that it will be a string.  The function definition would look like:

```
def is_true(n):
```

And then in the body of the function you use `n` to reference the value that is passed in by the caller.

To call the function on a specific value, you do:

```
is_true("3884892993")
```

Side suggestion:  Think of more explanatory names for your functions and variables.  For instance, it seems like your function might be reasonably called `is_valid_card_number`.

Comment: Hi, if called the function on a specfic value would it recognise to use n as the specfic value and then carry out the rest of the function?

Comment: Yes, n will hold the value you're passing in your is_true("3884892993") call.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wikipedia article on the Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm):

```
def is_luhn_valid(cc):
    num = map(int, str(cc))
    return sum(num[::-2] + [sum(divmod(d * 2, 10)) for d in num[-2::-2]]) % 10 == 0
```

Comment: Sadly I'm not allowed to blatantley plagiarise that, have to write something original, which is a lot to ask for someone who has only 3 weeks experience :(

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your function is supposed to do, but here are some remarks.

First of all, if you define the function then you use the following syntax

```
def is_true(n):
    # do something
```

you can call this function like this `is_true("3884892993")`, i.e. you can pass string as `n`. Your function now need to treat variable `n` as a string. So you can use

```
number = [int(d) for d in n]
```

which will result in converting string into a list of digits.

One more remark: you used a `return` statement inside your `is_true` function. This statement will stop executing the function and return the value. Every code below `return` will never be executed.

Comment: The function is meant to accept an input string which is 11 numbers, then with those numbers take the alternating numbers starting with the penultimate digit and working backwards, double those digits and then sum the digits e.g. if you had 18 and 3 you would do 1 + 8 + 3. Then add that sum to the sum of the remaining digits that weren't doubled, then work out if it is a multiple of 10, if it is print true and if not then print false. I'm not sure how complex doing that would be to an expert but to me, having only started to learn python 3 weeks ago it is impossible.

Comment: Sorry, on the second line it is supposed to read 'alternating digits'

Comment: Also I have no idea why I included a 'return' in there, thanks for the spot.

Answer (score 0):

May be like this. I leave your comments

```
def is_valid(n): #n is the number to be checked.
    numbers = [int(y) for y in n] #converts the string into a list of useable digits.
    double_alt = [sum([int(i) for i in str(x*2)]) for x in numbers[-2::-2]]   #doubles      and sum if more than 10each element of the list altern1.
    sum1 = sum(double_alt) # adds together all the doubled items of the list.
    sum2 = sum(numbers[-1::-2]) #sums the other set of alternating digits.
    sumtotal = sum1 + sum2 #works out the total sum to be worked with.
    return not sumtotal % 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an implementation of the luhn algorithm that I had to make recently.

```
def is_valid_luhn(cc):
    return not sum([sum(divmod(int(d) * 2, 10)) for d in cc[-2::-2]] + [int(d) for d in cc[-1::-2]]) % 10
    #                          | double |       |--- every -2th --|            |--- every -1th --|
    #                          |--------- step 1 -----------------|
    #              |------------- sum doubled digits --------------|   |-- sum undoubled digits --|
    #          |---------------------- step 2: sum doubled/undoubled digits -----------------------|
    #      |-------------------------- step 3: sum % 10 == 0 --> not sum % 10 --------------------------|
```

Or if you'd like a more verbose version:

```
def is_valid_luhn(cc):
    total = 0
    # Double and sum every 2nd digit starting at -2.
    for d in cc[-2::-2]:
        # divmod(d*2, 10) returns (d*2 // 10, d*2 % 10)
        # sum(divmod) return (d*2 // 10) + (d*2 % 10)
        total += sum(divmod(int(d) * 2, 10))
    # Sum every 2nd digit starting at -1.
    for d in cc[-1::-2]:
        total += int(d)
    # Check module 10 of total: total % 10 == 0 --> not total % 10
    return not total % 10
```